# SharePoint Hosted App Site Logo

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How I can change site logo on the app page? I know several ways to do it.

1. Updating the logo using javascript
2. Using a custom master page

Are there another ways?

Comment: You can also use PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You might use JavaScript / jQuery to change the logo *on the fly*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ChangeLogo();
   });
function ChangeLogo()
{
    $(".ms-siteicon-a img").attr('src', '../Images/logo.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your logo in App.manifest of app.To do that you have to add logo image in some folder and give ref of the image in app.maninfest file.

Comment: You're referring to the App's icon, but Nikolay is asking about the logo in the site itself.

Comment: Ohh Ok, the term app logo referred to as Icon of app which will be displayed in store for the app. So I thought that he might asking for same.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I achieved this by adding this to the App.css

```
.ms-siteicon-img {
    display: none;
}

.ms-siteicon-a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('../Images/MyLogo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 180px;
    height: 64px;
}
```